# Filter in sql query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

My sample table data is:
[image: Table Data]

and my sql query is:

```
SELECT
Distinct
   CASE CHARINDEX( '?', SessionURL)
       WHEN 0 THEN SessionURL
       ELSE LEFT(SessionURL, CHARINDEX( '?', SessionURL) - 1) END AS VisitPage, count(*) as [VisitTime] 
FROM SessionTracker  
 group by SessionURL
order by [VisitTime] desc
```

Query run sucessfully and returns a value with out query string.Means result from above data is:
[image: result]
But I want a result only in  a format:

```
Default
Modules
```

Is it possible this type of filter in sql query.If yes suggest a way.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The same way as you filter the querystring, filter on the / and the . You need the `SUBSTRING` function. To find the last occurence of the /, use the `REVERSE` function.

ie.

```
select pagename, COUNT(*)
from
(
    select 
        reverse(case CHARINDEX('/', withoutsuf) when 0 then withoutsuf 
        else LEFT(withoutsuf,CHARINDEX('/', withoutsuf)-1 ) end) as pagename
    from
    (
        select 
            substring(withoutq, CHARINDEX('.', withoutq)+1, LEN(withoutq)) withoutsuf
        from
        (
            select
                REVERSE(
                    CASE CHARINDEX( '?', SessionURL) 
                    WHEN 0 THEN SessionURL 
                    ELSE LEFT(SessionURL, CHARINDEX( '?', SessionURL) - 1) END) as withoutq
            from SessionTracker
        ) v
    ) v
) v
group by pagename
```

Answer (score 0):

try  this

```
declare @Path varchar(500)='http://somename/some_name.aspx'
SELECT  replace(substring(@Path,len(@Path)-
CHARINDEX('/',REVERSE(@Path))+2,len(@Path)),'.aspx','')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table(path varchar(100))
insert into @t (path)
select 'http://localhost:58588/default.aspx'  union all
select 'http://localhost:58588/default.aspx'  union all
select 'http://localhost:58588/super-user/modules.aspx'  

select 
    distinct replace(right(path,charindex('/',reverse(path))-1),'.aspx','') 
from 
    @t
```